# ng-mocks: NG0304: 'ng-mocks-ButtonComponent' is not a known element

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

I am using ng-mocks with Angular. While running the test case, I am getting below error

> console.error
> NG0304: 'ng-mocks-ButtonComponent' is not a known element (used in the 'i' component > template):
>
> 1. If 'ng-mocks-ButtonComponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part > of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
> 2. If 'ng-mocks-ButtonComponent' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to > the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
describe('ButtonComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    return MockBuilder(ButtonComponent, ButtonModule);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    const fixture = MockRender(ButtonComponent);
    expect(fixture.point.componentInstance).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should have icon as input decorator for the button component', () => {
    const fixture = MockRender(ButtonComponent);
    expect(fixture.point.componentInstance.icon).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: Test setup looks fine, can we also see ButtonComponent?

Comment: ```
@Component({ selector: 'button[my-button]', exportAs: 'myButton', styleUrls: [
'./button.component.scss'], templateUrl: './button.component.html', encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, }) export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit { @Input() btnIcon; @Input() btnType; }
```

Comment: Perhaps try `selector: 'my-button'` and see if the same error occurs. Something odd is happening with the component name since the error mentions `'ng-mocks-ButtonComponent'`

Comment: Could you share the decoration of the component? Also, which version of `ng-mocks` do you use?

Comment: Worth saying as i stumbled into this recently, you can get this message *ALLOT* if you're using the MockRenderFactory and there's a issue. Something you'd quickly find and solve if using simple MockRender, but in using MockRenderFactory it obfuscates this error away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been reported and fixed already: https://github.com/help-me-mom/ng-mocks/issues/3515

Please upgrade [`ng-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) to the latest version.